# VESTA object selection not working reliably

Tags: vesta

I am now working with VESTA and need to hide certain polyhedra for plotting purposes.
I am having trouble selecting single and groups of polyhedra though, as the program selects a random other object of the same nature.

Anyone has an idea why this may be happening? I tried updating the graphics drivers already as indicated here https://groups.google.com/g/vesta-discuss/c/5YY3aPS_C5A, but to no improvement.

Thanks!

Comment: +1 Welcome to our forum!